# cross compiling ( Android-NDK-Cross-Compile-Build-Automator ) open source utility bindfs for android & other bind mount solutions

Tags: android, permissions, filesystems, storage, selinux

**Background**

I moved to my new AT&T Samsung phone. unfortunately this is is at Android 10 with `selinux enforced` 
there is no way I can change it to `permissive` and anyway with the proven insecurity it is not worth doing it.

My  `WhatsApp` folder has to be `bound` to a specific `ext4 partition` I created on my micro SD card. 
 earlier with a custom ROM running `permissive Linux`  this was possible without much Ado.

**What I am trying to do**

- with `enforced SeLinux stock ROM`  running Android 10 I would like to `bind mount`  my `WhatsApp` data to `/data/sdxt3/WhatsApp`
  which is the `ext4 partition`  I created that I earlier  mentioned .
  Used the following guides for this:

  [Correctly Bind Mount Android Folder](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/217741/how-to-bind-mount-a-folder-inside-sdcard-with-correct-permissions)
  [BindFs Guide](https://github.com/agnostic-apollo/bindfs)
  [Fuse Guide](https://github.com/agnostic-apollo/fuse)
  [Android-NDK-Cross-Compile-Build-Automator](https://github.com/agnostic-apollo/Android-NDK-Cross-Compile-Build-Automator)

  `bindfs` is a brilliant idea but the Utilities needed to compile are very fragile & and I am running into a whole plethora of errors.
   *Here is my compile output studded with errors* -[output](https://paste.c-net.org/RetainedSeating)

**my questions** 
-how do I `compile bindfs` correctly for my Android architecture which is  `arm64-v8a` ( and also need 1 for `armeabi-v7a )`  . the guide online is extremely convoluted especially for a noob like me
-with enforced Linux what are the options other than bindfs to achieve the above functionality. 
maybe this may sound rhetoric because there isn't any AFAIK ( `adoptable storage`  given my situation is not an option ) but I am nonetheless hopelessly optimistic.

-the source code for my stock ROM is available I would like to modify it so it can support `ext4`  natively without me writing a custom script to Mount it. How do I  compile a `custom kernel` for my `ROM` with the kind of modifications I want .Can someone point me to a detailed guide without any ambiguity.

Comment: for arm64 there is [this](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=4349826312261681311) one (your first link) or arm32/64 [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3709380&page=23)

Comment: I used the  former link long ago and it threw errors. I needed for `arm64-v8a` any clue  for that. Thanks for coming periodically to my rescue

Comment: ok thx. `arm-v7a` worked. I had assumed getting a new one for `arm-v8a` . I used all combinations of `bindfs` command but I cannot get it to create new files & dir's so whatsApp d/l's fail. My Bad SeLinux Logging is disabled & I cant get it to enable. How do I get this thing to create - its getting there.... up close but still short

Comment: `bindfs -o nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,context=u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0 -u 0 -g 9997 -p a-rwx,ug+rw,ugo+X --create-with-perms=a-rwx,ug+rw,ugo+X --xattr-none --chown-ignore --chgrp-ignore --chmod-ignore $DIR/WhatsApp /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/WhatsApp` followed to the T but also tried various other perms & combos none is giving create folder / file access  & I wonder what's the issue here I am on Android 10 `# getprop ro.build.version.release 
10
m20lte:/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin # getprop ro.build.version.sdk 
29
`

Comment: it works only within same mount namespace. create a service.d script all fine

Comment: thanks alecxs for bearing with me as I wrap around this.My Magisk is set to `global Namespace`...how can it matter then ?

Comment: ok i found out something more hopefully useful `02-09 01:15:41.761  9421  9421 W com.whatsapp: type=1400 audit(0.0:15540): avc: denied { create } for comm=4D65646961446F776E6C6F61642023 name="LW9n+rkip578Ox9pPGthBD5DGfO7rIMxJyDHRHjQ9ZY=.tmp" scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c122,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
` Now this is recreating the scenario on another Android 9 phone with `SeLinux` state changeable ( the other 1 is perm. `enforced`). So the issue could be untrusted app. Does it mean I have to recompile kernel with updated policy OR any work-around ?

Comment: assuming recreation reflects the correct state in the other phone where `SeLinux` is forced enforced but there isn't any logging

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241847/discussion-between-user1874594-and-alecxs).